# Question closed as Typo, but provides insight/use to further readers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16340072/4875631), which if you search google, happens to be the first result:

[image]

Now, we had another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52907065/4875631) that was asked today, where a user encountered this error when inserting into the database. My initial instinct was to try and search for a dupe, but ended up answering the question, as most of the answers I found were due to column counts being off.

Now, my question relates to the close reason: This appears to be a widespread issue, and while it's mostly caused by simple typos, I still find it can be useful to future visitors. In my opinion, I think adding another answer onto the original one with something along the lines of "This can also happen if you incorrectly add starting and ending parenthesis `()` ", which may have avoided this question all together.

I'm stuck because, I'm unsure of whether to reopen this (I doubt the community would see my way, without this explanation), or how I should proceed. Should this just be left closed, or should I perhaps create another wiki-question for this error, explaining all the individual cases why "Error Code: 1136" could fail?

Comment: That isn't a "common gotcha" kind of question the same way a surprising syntactic rule in some other language might be. That's the sort of thing that it's very difficult to make a canonical Q&A for because the error message is self-explanatory and not much more can really be said than "double-check your queries". The accepted answer to that particular question doesn't even say *that*.

Answer (score 2):

The only other circumstance I'd be *okay* with keeping around would be one in which a developer omits the target columns as part of a table with an `AUTO INCREMENT` column, so that would mean that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5746155/1079354) fits that role fairly nicely.

Other than that, I'm ***really*** not interested in keeping this particular question around.  It's an error that solves itself and I don't see much in the way of wholesale "value" or insight here.  Kind of feels like one has painted a bikeshed in what is *really* a problem with a typo.

Comment: Typos to me, are things like a missing semi-colon at the end of a line, or misspelling a function name. In this case, an error is caused by multiple problems: The result of omitting a parameter, or adding a parenthesis before and after something that inherently you think wouldn't be an issue. This can be a confusing situation for most developers, and not something readily apparent, unless you know what you're looking for.

Comment: A typo is both a misspelling and an omission of a part of grammar.  This can manifest itself as simple as a semicolon; this may be a case when a developer an entire piece of code.  Besides, it isn't like a developer is paralyzed and has absolutely no clue on what to do next, since the error message tells them everything they need to know.  Why should we have a question like that here?

Comment: The question has been viewed over 35k times. The reason for the close reason, is that it's "unlikely" to help future readers, but if users are heading there, then that tends to make me believe in this case, even though it may be considered a typo, it should be reopened as it has proven likely to help future readers.

Comment: @FrankerZ:  That translates to a measly [547 views per month](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=35,513+%2F+(+5+years+5+months)), given how old the question actually is.  This is regrettably the top search result on Google when it genuinely shouldn't be, and even if it is the top result, it seems to be the case that a vast majority of people who encounter this error message aren't looking for it.

Comment: @Makoto: To be fair, an average of 547 views per month over the course of 5 and a half years is nothing to sneeze at considering it's *65 months* we're talking about. That said, it's indeed regrettable that it's the top result, yes, considering the Q&A itself doesn't actually offer any genuine insight to readers beyond "if you're reading this, you made a boo-boo, check your query again".

Comment: @BoltClock:  Keeping along the lines of this, the [in]famous [String comparison question](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3,330,679++%2F+(+9+years,+8+months)) clocks in at 28K views/month, and the [Java NPE question](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2,034,329++%2F+(+10+years)) clocks in at 203K views/month.  Both of these questions are fairly obviously answered, like the MySQL version.  The difference is that the MySQL error code is narrowly and accurately prescriptive of the solution that needs to be taken, whereas the other two aren't *as* prescriptive.

Comment: Yeah, and that's what sets those two questions apart from this one; why those two questions shouldn't be closed with the "typo/unlikely to help future readers" reason.